# iMac shows a "flashing globe" screen and then continues to startup normally

Tags: startup, netboot

I have another particular issue with my iMac. Every time I hold the N key on startup to boot from a NetBoot server, it shows a globe icon (I know it was flashing) for just 20-30 seconds and then it just continues to start up normally. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the current macOS version? If you reboot your Mac and hold Command+Opt+R, do you see a spinning globe and eventually a Recovery Console?

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page - do you have a net boot server running locally?

Comment: No, I DON'T! Stop asking me that!

Comment: There's you're answer - you need a Netboot server for it to boot off the network.  Were you instead thinking about booting from [Recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT201314)?